# Image generation from table data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm looking to generate images/image files, basic rectangles made up of smaller squares, with varying colours based on data in my Access 2003 db tables. Basically the table has fields storing rating values which determines the colour of squares on the face of the rectangle.

My search so far has not been fruitful.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to do this.  For example:

```
Sub ImageMagickTest()
Dim im As Object

    Set im = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage")
    im.Convert "-size", "100x100", "canvas:#0000FF", "C:\Blue.png"
End Sub
```

The relevant section of the ImageMagick help is [Canvas Creation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#solid).